ZFS RAID 10 on Ubuntu 24.04: Issues with /dev/disk/by-id/
I'm having a small issue with a Github Repository that I created.  The intent of the Repository was to automatically install Ubuntu 24.04 on a ZFS RAID 10.  I chose ZFS RAID 10 as this is meant to eventually become a cloudstack host, so I require the data read/write speeds a little higher(double) than that of a raidz1 or raidz2.  Now this repository is meant to be run from a Live CD environment.  It can be as simple as a single command to get something up and running, or customizable via the performance of a git clone and a few file edits (your own netplan config, a changed /etc/default/grub). The repository I created was based on the mashup of two guides from OpenZFS(Debian/Ubuntu).
You can find the repository here .
Now running ZFS requires you to be a little more specific about what drives you are using.  For example, using /dev/sda is unreliable as the disks connected could change if you are in a degraded state.  That is why I chose to use /dev/disk/by-id/.
That is where I hit a bit of a snag.  Now I've included screenshots of the commands and command outputs that I use to list disk drives in both the Live CD environment and the installed Ubuntu 24.04 environment.  Basically, the scsi disks that were listed in the Live CD are no longer present in the Ubuntu 24.04 Installation.  Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?  Am I missing a dependency or is there a configuration error?
The command I use is:
ls -A /dev/disk/by-id/ | sed '/-part/d;/usb/d'

LiveCD:


ubuntu-server@ubuntu-server:~$ ls -A /dev/disk/by-id/ | sed '/-part/d;/usb/d'
ata-ST12000VN0007-2GS116_ZJV42Y5X
ata-ST12000VN0007-2GS116_ZJV4HRM7
ata-ST12000VN0007-2GS116_ZJV4Q8GG
ata-ST12000VN0007-2GS116_ZJV58DGK
scsi-0ATA_ST12000VN0007-2G_ZJV42Y5X
scsi-0ATA_ST12000VN0007-2G_ZJV4HRM7
scsi-0ATA_ST12000VN0007-2G_ZJV4Q8GG
scsi-0ATA_ST12000VN0007-2G_ZJV58DGK
scsi-1ATA_ST12000VN0007-2GS116_ZJV42Y5X
scsi-1ATA_ST12000VN0007-2GS116_ZJV4HRM7
scsi-1ATA_ST12000VN0007-2GS116_ZJV4Q8GG
scsi-1ATA_ST12000VN0007-2GS116_ZJV58DGK
scsi-35000c500b51c2231
scsi-35000c500b5de35c9
scsi-35000c500b6656d48
scsi-35000c500b6682eef
scsi-SATA_ST12000VN0007-2G_ZJV42Y5X
scsi-SATA_ST12000VN0007-2G_ZJV4HRM7
scsi-SATA_ST12000VN0007-2G_ZJV4Q8GG
scsi-SATA_ST12000VN0007-2G_ZJV58DGK
wwn-0x5000c500b51c2231
wwn-0x5000c500b5de35c9
wwn-0x5000c500b6656d48
wwn-0x5000c500b6682eef


Ubuntu 24.04 Installation:


jeff@cloudstack:~$ ls -A /dev/disk/by-id/ | sed '/-part/d;/usb/d'
ata-ST12000VN0007-2GS116_ZJV42Y5X
ata-ST12000VN0007-2GS116_ZJV4HRM7
ata-ST12000VN0007-2GS116_ZJV4Q8GG
ata-ST12000VN0007-2GS116_ZJV58DGK
wwn-0x5000c500b51c2231
wwn-0x5000c500b5de35c9
wwn-0x5000c500b6656d48
wwn-0x5000c500b6682eef


Any other tips on the automated install is very much appreciated.
